# Paypal Developer API NVP

Tags: api, paypal, nvp

I am using the standard paypal developer API (NVP) to get current inventory levels:

https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=BMGetInventory&VERSION=95.0&USER=____&PWD=____&SIGNATURE=____&HOSTEDBUTTONID=_____

But, I have a concern... If the api is enabled and the key is compromised somehow, what is the worst case scenario? For example: it looks like it is possible to send payments using the API. Is there a second tier of verification of payments that happens outside the API?

I have spent around 30 minutes researching the topic without any clarity in terms of what kind of financial damage could be done if an api information is compromised.

Comment: NVP calls are made **server-side**. If your server and/or network is/are compromised,  gaining access to your authentication information is just the beginning of your headaches. Depending on which API you are referring to, you'll have to meet **PCI COMPLIANCE** requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If your PayPal API credentials are compromised then someone can make API calls on your behalf. This includes sending and/or withdrawing money from your account.

There are some ways to limit the permissions of a PayPal API credential on the pages where you set the credential up, so you might be able to create a key that is somewhat less dangerous. It has changed over time so I can't offer details; google and/or log in to your account and look.

And yes, PayPal has lots of fraud detection that it runs internally on payments, but they have no legal responsibility to figure out that your API has has been stolen and I would strongly recommend not relying on them to save your bacon in such a case.

Protect your keys, especially ones with access to your money.